# Releasing mediaplayer resource of parent activity from child activity

Tags: android, parent-child, android-mediaplayer

I am initializing a media player resource in say activity A. Then when I move from Activity A to Activity B, i am playing that sound.

Now the problem is I want to release the resource when I exit The child activity B,but I am not being able to do so. Any suggestions ? thanks in advance

Edit: here's what I am doing: I click on a button in activity A to go to activity B and at the same time start the media player. Now I want to release the Media player resource when I exit activity B. So i wrote this in the on destroy method of activity B:

```
{
 super.onDestroy();

 this.getParent().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        obj1.entry.release(); //entry is mediaplayer and obj1 in A's object     
        obj1.entry=null;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use Activity.runOnUiThread()

Comment: when you exit from the activity B , mediplayer still play?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar..yes it still plays

Comment: you can define mediaplayer as static, and then when you exit from B you can use **A.my_media.stop();**

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar: Sorry but this didn't work. I have edited the question.Please take a look

Comment: Thanks guys..I solved the problem..it was quite simple actually.

I figured when exiting from the child activity, the parent's activity on resume method would be called. So I released the media resources in that method.